# DDClinet Google Domains

Tags: google-domains, ddclient

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and it report having DDClient 3.8.2-2ubuntu2. We own a domain in google domains and have added the synthetic record but so far zero success in getting it to update through DDClient. Anyone know what'g going wrong? Can you share a working example? I'm copying and pasting username, password and domain name so I can't have a typo in them.

First error sounds to me like it can't find the A record mentioned, but I'm sure it exists.

```
CONNECT:  domains.google.com
CONNECTED:  using SSL
SENDING:  GET /nic/update?system=dyndns&hostname=name.example.com&myip=numbers HTTP/1.0
SENDING:   Host: domains.google.com
SENDING:   Authorization: Basic infostuffher
SENDING:   User-Agent: ddclient/3.8.2
SENDING:   Connection: close
SENDING:
RECEIVE:  HTTP/1.0 200 OK
RECEIVE:  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
RECEIVE:  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
RECEIVE:  P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
RECEIVE:  Date: Mon, 07 May 2018 14:47:26 GMT
RECEIVE:  Expires: Mon, 07 May 2018 14:47:26 GMT
RECEIVE:  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
RECEIVE:  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
RECEIVE:  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
RECEIVE:  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
RECEIVE:  Server: GSE
RECEIVE:  Set-Cookie: NID=129=hash;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Tue, 06-Nov-2018 14:47:26 GMT;HttpOnly
RECEIVE:  Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
RECEIVE:  Accept-Ranges: none
RECEIVE:  Vary: Accept-Encoding
RECEIVE:
RECEIVE:  nohost
FAILED:   updating name.example.com: nohost: The hostname specified does not exist in the database
file /etc/ddclient.conf, line 11: Invalid Value for keyword 'protocol' = 'googledomains'
file /etc/ddclient.conf, line 11: Invalid Value for keyword 'protocol' = 'googledomains'
file /etc/ddclient.conf, line 11: Invalid Value for keyword 'protocol' = 'googledomains'
unable to determine IP address
```

Config for the above

```
# Configuration file for ddclient
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

# service and lookup
daemon=900
verbose=yes

# google account info
ssl=yes
protocol=googledomains
login=login
password=password
name.example.com
```

This one is using the "preferred" method with DDClient that supports google DNS but it sounds like the one that's included in Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't? Why not??

```
 CONNECT:  domains.google.com
 CONNECTED:  using SSL
 SENDING:  GET /nic/update?system=dyndns&hostname=name.example.com&myip=somenumbers HTTP/1.0
 SENDING:   Host: domains.google.com
 SENDING:   Authorization: Basic 
 SENDING:   User-Agent: ddclient/3.8.2
 SENDING:   Connection: close
 SENDING:
 RECEIVE:  HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 RECEIVE:  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
 RECEIVE:  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 RECEIVE:  P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
 RECEIVE:  Date: Mon, 07 May 2018 14:47:26 GMT
 RECEIVE:  Expires: Mon, 07 May 2018 14:47:26 GMT
 RECEIVE:  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
 RECEIVE:  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 RECEIVE:  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 RECEIVE:  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
 RECEIVE:  Server: GSE
 RECEIVE:  Set-Cookie: NID=129=bunchofnumbers;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Tue, 06-Nov-2018 14:47:26 GMT;HttpOnly
 RECEIVE:  Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
 RECEIVE:  Accept-Ranges: none
 RECEIVE:  Vary: Accept-Encoding
 RECEIVE:
 RECEIVE:  nohost
 FAILED:   updating name.example.com: nohost: The hostname specified does not exist in the database
```

Config file for the above

```
# Configuration file for ddclient
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

# service and lookup
daemon=900
verbose=yes

# google account info
protocol=dyndns2
use=web
server=domains.google.com
ssl=yes
login=login
password=password
name.example.com
```

Comment: Finally figured it out

 # Configuration file for ddclient
 #
 # /etc/ddclient.conf

 # service
 daemon=900
 verbose=yes

 # Lookup IP
 use=web
 web=checkip.dyndns.com

 # google account info
 ssl=yes
 protocol=dyndns2
 server=domains.google.com
 login=
 password=
 thing.example.com